# Build not setting correct path

Tags: angular, build

I have an app that is in a sub-directory off the main page of my main app that is totally independent of anything else. When I go a "ng build --prod" it looks for all the asset files on the main page and not in the sub-directory.

example
mainpage.com is my primary page
mainpage.com/newapp is where the new app is
mainpage.com/newapp/assets is where all my images are (there are only 6 so I did not create a sub-direcotry)
mainpage.com/assets is where the compiled version of the app is looking for the images.

I do have `<base href="./">` in my index.html file and it works fine when running on my local server (ng serve -- localhost:4200).

Any suggestions on how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

`ng build --prod --deploy-url /newapp/ --base-href /newapp`